# How to catch read permission denial in Firebase using the js web API

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've set up the rules so that only users in a white-list can read the database. Everything works fine for the white-listed users. However, I could not figure out how to handle the other cases, especially the authenticated users who are not on the white-list. Since they fail the security rules, the .on('value') listener doesn't fire, and it doesn't raise any exception either. Please enlighten me on how to detect authenticated users without read permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `on()` method takes a so-called "cancel callback", which will be called when the user doesn't have (or loses) permission to listen at the location. From the [reference documentation for `on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on):

> cancelCallbackOrContext
>
> Optional
>
> An optional callback that will be notified if your event subscription is ever canceled because your client does not have permission to read this data (or it had permission but has now lost it). This callback will be passed an `Error` object indicating why the failure occurred.

So in most cases, use something like:

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
})
```